# Sufficient condition for the convergence of the time average of a dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Consider a dynamical system defined by a 1-d unimodal map. Suppose that the topological entropy of the system is positive. Then does the time average of f converge to a constant? If so, give me any reference.